# Set the orientation of iPhone's MoviePlayer in a Webview

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to set the orientation of a movie that is opened in a Webview? I can do this programatically through the app, or I can add a parameter to the Quicktime loaded in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all parameters, but the orientation was arbitrary, I thought.

How it works: The dimensions of your poster image determine whether your video opens landscape or in portrait mode. So poster images that are wider than high will open landscape, poster images that are higher than wide, will open a movie in portrait mode.

Example:

object width="300" height="200"....  : Landscape

object width="200" height="300"....  : Portrait